# Comparing two values in a dataframe while iterating using iterrows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I run the code below, I get this error: 
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')

```
def execute_fnc(x):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        if df['first'] < df['last']:
            df['a'] = False
            df['b'] = df['c']
        else:
            df['a'] = True
            df['b'] = df['c'] + df['last'] - df['first']
    return df


df.apply(execute_fnc, axis=1)
```

Comment: can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You're combining two of the worst pandas idioms to create an antipattern sandwich: iteration and apply. Please don't.

Comment: @cs95: I soooo like the term `antipattern sandwich`. Big thumbs-up :))

Comment: Rob, cs95 is a point.  Please post some data and explain what you are trying to do.  I am certain, the SO community can help you find an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often newcomers to Pandas from general purpose Python treat the data frame as a collection of lists/tuples. However, Pandas and even Numpy structures maintain the vectorized construct where the `Series` (i.e., column of `DataFrame`) similar to N-d array can be seen as a vector of more than one element and allows arithmetic and logical operations to be run on all its elements at **once** without looping across every element. This can include `apply` (a hidden loop).

Therefore, instead of the scalar logic construct of `if/else` logically checking the truthfulness of *one* value (raising the error for more than one value), consider running conditional logic on entire columns using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) that checks the truthfulness of all column elements at once. Do note the reverse of inequality for `True` condition to precede `False` condition:

```
df['a'] = np.where(df['first'] >= df['last'], True, False)

df['b'] = np.where(df['first'] >= df['last'], df['c'] + df['last'] - df['first'], df['c'])
```

Alternatively, combine both assigned columns:

```
df['a'] = df['first'] >= df['last']

df['b'] = np.where(df['a'], df['c'] + df['last'] - df['first'], df['c'])
```

Comment: You are right, I am new at this, and the vectoring makes sense.I have to learn more about it, but this worked and was very helpful. Thank you.